# Meaning of netbeans ide navigator icons?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

What are the meanings of the icons displayed in the Netbeans IDE navigator? Is there a legend posted somewhere online? I did google before asking, thank you.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry I dont use Netbeans but don't they have tooltip?

Comment: No tooltips for the Mac OS X version, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

- Open the online help (Help -> Help Contents)
- Click on the "Search" tab
- Type "icon"
- Hit enter
- The first topic in the result ("Java File and Object Node Icons") lists all icons used in the IDE

Here is a screenshot of the online help:
[image: Online help]

Maybe this help is not available in your edition as you seem to be using PHP (which you could have told us from the beginning)

Oracle has put the NetBeans help online, so the icons can be viewed here as well:
 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/work_java_code.htm#r1c1-t5

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name, but no that doesn't identify these icons.

Comment: It sure does, see the screenshot I added

Comment: I tried re-installing the full version. The icon legend is not there in the help file. I apologize for not giving the version I was using.

Comment: I filed a bug report on it. Apparently the help files for some versions of the Mac OS X netbeans IDE are missing the legend for the navigator icons. Even re-installing the complete version didn't help I finally had to manually add the Java plugin to get that part of the help file. Anyway thank you for trying to help and I wanted to let you know what I found finally fixed it.

Comment: @annonemoose I just had the same issue with NetBeans 8.1 where the icons don't show up in the help file. Here are a few links I found that show what the icons I was interesting in are: https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb81/netbeans/develop/work_java_code.htm#NBDAG2251  https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html  I never did find the one describing the `Projects` tab. :-(